# Windows form background Image, make bigger on maximise

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2008, forms

I am creating a timer solution.  User enters hrs, mins secs, into text boxes and then clicks button to start.  I wanted the timer to be small so it can be hidden at the top corner of the screen.  I have sized a background image to this size so it fits nicely in the small form.  However I also want the user to be able to maximise the form and take up the whole screen if they want.  However the image obviously stays at the original size.  Is there any possible way to avoid this (i.e can i add an image which will be used if maximise is pressed.  Hopefully i have made sense with this question.

Thanks - Colly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have two images in resources. Use smaller one if app is in smaller mode and use bigger one if app is in maximized mode.

`Form.SizeChanged` event is raised every time there is any change in form size. You can handle this event and based on parameters you can find out whether you should change the image or not

Comment: thanks Haris - for a simple test i did the folloing.         private void CountDownTimer_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Image col = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\colinmck\Desktop\Timer\CountDownTimer\CountDownTimer\test.bmp");
            BackgroundImage = col;
        } - It was just a black image i created for a test. Now it changes and uses it when I maximise - but it stays when i minimize back - I can obv create an image variable for my smaller image but what way would i vary between the two - have some kind of bool called max/min?  Many Thanks

Comment: Oh and one further comment - what its the best way to move the position of the txt boxes/buttons etc when the maximise button is clicked to center them and then move them back to their original position if minimise is clicked - Cheers.

Comment: regarding your first comment, Well you will have to note the resize event parameters, when parameter becomes less than a certain threshold you can switch the image back to smaller and same is the case when user increase size and goes up to a certain limit you can switch the image to larger one. Regarding your second comment, that should be a separate question :)

Comment: Thanks for your response Haris.  I will perhaps open a new thread for my seperate question at some stage if I cant get it working by experimenting moving x/y co-ordinates.  However Im not sure what you mean or how to capture the resize event parameters?

Comment: Actually think got it - Cheers Haris :)

Answer (score 1):

Hook `Form.SizeChanged` event or `Resize` event should work.

Answer (score 1):

Set `BackgroundImageLayout` of the form to `Stretch`